# Detect apple's forced phantom banner in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile-safari

I'm not an iOS developer, and know little less about Safari's configuration by apple.
But Please, hear me out.

I have universal links configured, and I understand that if the App is installed, visiting the website with Safari browser will automatically show a *phantom banner* to open the page in the app. This seems one of the policies apple included in their *Universal Link* settings.

- Image below shows an example of the *Phantom banner*
  [image]

My question is: **How can I detect the presence of this *Apple's Phantom banner* through JavaScript?**

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, currently, there is no way to detect the Phantom banner if the universal link is enabled in safari.
You cannot remove it through JS also it has no presence in the DOM.

Try integrating a 3rd party plugin like Firebase or Branch.
I tried firebase hoping it can resolve the issue and below is a summary.

It will create a dynamic link to your webpage which is nothing but a wrapper on your deep link.
But with that you will lose the ability to click on your webpage link and open the App, instead, you will have to use the dynamic link to open the App.

The Dynamic link can be on your domain or on a custom domain.
Here is some more information on domain configuration
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains

In my case, the ask was to link directly to the website link so this did not help much. But if the ask is to open the App on a link click then it can help as the Apple App Association file will not be on your domain and you will not see the phantom banner.